# How to let the pageview.builder when it reached its last index and the user try to swipe right to review the first child of the pageview

Tags: flutter

I'm using to display multi image in the pageview.builder where the user can swipe left or right to view them,i want when the user reaches the last index of the pageview to review the first index again for the user, not the end in the last index.

```
  AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: (currentIndex) {
                    Provider.of<SellerUpdateImageCount>(context,
                            listen: false)
                        .changeImageCount();
                    index = currentIndex;
                    // print('yes');
                  },
                  itemCount: images.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Answer (score 0):

remove itemCount and try

```
 AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            child: PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              onPageChanged: (currentIndex) {
                Provider.of<SellerUpdateImageCount>(context,
                        listen: false)
                    .changeImageCount();
                index = currentIndex;
                // print('yes');
              },
              here : comment out 
              //itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```